# Proc contents in macro VARNUM

Tags: sas

I am exporting the SAS contents to excel file and it works good., however the VARNUM option doesnt seem to work and the variables are in alphabetical order in the excel sheet.

here is the loop.

```
proc sql;
    select count(Name) into :NumOfDatasets from Datas;
    select Name into :Dataset1-:Dataset%trim(%left(&NumOfDatasets)) from     datas;
quit;

%do index = 1 %to &NumOfDatasets;

    proc contents data=&ImportLibrary..&&Dataset&index. varnum
    out=&ExportLibrary..&&Dataset&index. (keep=name label);run;

    proc export data=&ExportLibrary..&&Dataset&index.
    outfile="&ExportLocation"
    dbms=excelcs replace;
    sheet="&&Dataset&index";
    run;

%end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `varnum` option on `proc contents` affects only the report output of the procedure, not the dataset generated with the `out=` option.

You could just add a `proc sort` between your `contents` and `export` procedures (and move the `keep=` dataset option from the `contents` to the `export` procedure):

```
proc sql;
  select count(Name) into :NumOfDatasets from Datas;
  select Name into :Dataset1-:Dataset%trim(%left(&NumOfDatasets)) from datas;
quit;

%do index = 1 %to &NumOfDatasets;

  proc contents data=&ImportLibrary..&&Dataset&index.
                out=&ExportLibrary..&&Dataset&index.;
  run;

  proc sort data=&ExportLibrary..&&Dataset&index.;
    by varnum;
  run;

  proc export data=&ExportLibrary..&&Dataset&index.(keep=name label)
              outfile="&ExportLocation"
              dbms=excelcs
              replace;
    sheet="&&Dataset&index";
  run;
%end;
```